# Laptop keyboard issues

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I have an Acer Aspire 5739g laptop that I've bought just about a year ago now, and have a few issues with it.

Mainly the keyboard. This keyboard is atrocious; the keys are spaced far apart so there are huge gaps for debris to get into, the keys are really weak and pop off (even the metal clip part on a few keys are bent just from normal usage! Wtf?! My <kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>5</kbd> keys are bent and are hard to press down), and they're very glossy which attracts fingerprints, dirt and stains very easily.

Anyway, I'm wondering a few things:

- is it possible to actually install a different keyboard on a laptop? Or are laptop keyboards built specific to its model?
- can I send a laptop back to the manufacturer to get the keyboard entirely replaced? (with no other work done)
- my keys damage extremely easily; once they pop off, they stay off - the plastic holding it usually breaks, and the metal thing that the plastic clips onto bends easily. What is the best way to clean my keyboard if I need to do it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keyboards for laptops are actually typically very easy to install. However, you need a keyboard that will fit your laptop.

I've actually replaced one for a similar model. It required popping off the top plate(where the power button is) and unscrewing like 2 screws, detaching a cable then undoing everything with the new keyboard.

http://www.cdsparts.com/p-538-new-acer-aspire-5410-5739-5739g-5810-5810t-5810tg-5810tz-7738-keyboard.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. To my knowledge there is no universal keyboard that can be installed into the laptop.  They are pretty Model specific.  You can purchase and [external keyboard](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=portable+laptop+keyboard&cid=12577543241617955194&ei=2j6STM3XH4rEiASDxNT2Dg&sa=title&ved=0CBcQ8wIwATgA#p) that's small and compact, but I'm not sure if that's what you are looking for.
2. Sending back the Laptop is entirely up to your warranty when you bought the laptop.  If it's still covered then you should be able to have them fix.  A word of caution though... I NEVER send my pc's/laptop back to the manufacturer with the hard drive still in it.  I would remove the hard drive before sending it.  I've also had terrible experiences where the laptop has come back worse than before I sent it.  That may be because it was DELL, but I don't know.
3. To clean my laptop I use eyeglass cleaning cloths.  They typically pick up most of the gunk.  You can also use cleaning alcohol cloths.  The moisture evaporates quickly thus protecting your electronics, and that gets the tougher "stains"

Answer (score 0):

A further tip for cleaning the keyboard: [Canned Air.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_duster)

Direct the straw between keys, at various angles (though these things work best if the can itself is kept mostly upright). This works well for blowing out dust and small debris.