# How do I remove the keyboard of an Acer Aspire 5739g laptop?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

Looking at the answers to my [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/189425), it sounds like my best bet is to replace the entire keyboard manually. This time, I'm aware of the problems and can take more precautions to preventing the issues that occurred from happening again.

Anyway, I have no idea how to disassemble this laptop and get the actual keyboard tray out. I cannot find any videos, tutorials or manuals describing what goes where.

Does anybody know how I can find out or what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not seen this model specifically, but I have seen others within the same series (and looking at pictures of replacement keyboards for yours, it appears the same).

On the top row of the keyboard, there should be a few plastic hinges that lock in to place. You just need to push these slightly back and tilt the top of the keyboard up whilst the bottom is still in place.

When at a larger angle, around 45 degrees, just push up and the bottom hinges will come out.

To put back, simply go in reverse - line up the bottom with the holes, then push the top down - making sure each of the top hinges snap in to place.

Comment: I see no hinges.

Comment: @Corey - maybe post a picture?

Comment: @Corey, hinges are the wrong word, I don't know a better on... sort of like a flap :S you just need a flat head screwdriver to push it in... I can't really say any more - if you don't know what I mean, it is possible you don't have the same keyboard.

Comment: I see little flat plastic clips, now that I take a closer look at it. Could that be what you're referring to? There's some on the sides as well.

Comment: @Corey I think so - Yes, I can't really describe what they are... latches would probably be the easiest thing... sort of like a Yale type lock closing on a door, they push in to place, you just need to use a flat head screwdriver and push it out!... It should require next to no force, if you are using much, careful - something may be wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the service manual for a 5738g, close as I could find

http://tim.id.au/laptops/acer/aspire%205738g%205738zg%205738z%205738%205338%205536%205536g%205236.pdf
.